# How to write this math equation in latex?

Tags: amsmath, math-operators, mathtools

[image]

I am new to Latex and I am struggling to write math equations. Does anybody know how to write this equation and the equation on the next line?

Comment: Welcome! Yes, a lot of people will know how to write it, but this site is not supposed to be a "please-do-it-for-me" one --- it's for learning and correcting mistakes. So you should post what you have tried. If you do not know how to start, you can read  https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-10 (or start from at https://www.learnlatex.org).

Comment: To add onto the point by Rmano, even if someone did want to do your work for you, you haven't accepted any of your previous questions answers as accepted (only if they answered your question ofc) so there is little incentive

Comment: Is there any reason for the operator `fib`  to be written in italic?

Comment: One tweak to some of the good answers below: I’d suggest you `\DeclareMathOperator\fib{fib}`, which will let you write `\fib(n)` just like `\log(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that

1. fib(n) means the n-th Fibonacci number
2. the square brackets denote the “nearest integer” (otherwise the formula is wrong
3. the asterisk denotes multiplication

You have two choices for fib(n), namely

```
\mathrm{fib}(n)
\mathit{fib}(n)
```

whereas just `fib(n)` would be wrong. Denoting multiplication with an asterisk is something I can't do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section{Upright}
\[
\mathrm{fib}(n)=\biggl[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\biggl(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\biggr)^{\!n}\biggr]\sim c\cdot1.62^n
\]
\section{Italic}
\[
\mathit{fib}(n)=\biggl[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\biggl(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\biggr)^{\!n}\biggr]\sim c\cdot1.62^n
\]

\end{document}
```

Take your pick and be consistent.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the sentence you put there are symbols that are not displayed.

Whati is "*"?

To the equation, try this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \mathrm{fib}(n) = \left[\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left(\dfrac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n} \, \right] \sim c^*1.62^n
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what is the `*` there for? It this meant to be multiplication?

Comment: I don't know, I did the same as the original image. probably yes, so it would be better to switch to \times

Comment: *fib* should probably be `\mathrm{fib}`; in any event, it us a "word", not three variables multiplying one another.  And the `*` in the original looks like a superscript: `c^*`; (I haven't any idea what it means).

Comment: thanks for your comments, I changed the code.